# Have any authors suggested mathematics-wide prefixes for "missing a quotient" and/or "missing an identity"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, terminology

The prefixes in the following terms both mean: "missing the obvious quotient by the obvious equivalence relation."

1. seminorm
2. pseudometric

Similarly, the prefixes in the following terms both mean: "missing identities"

1. semicategory
2. pseudoring

It would be nice if there was a prefix that could be used "mathematics wide" to mean "missing the identities," and another that could  be used to mean "missing the obvious quotient by the obvious equivalence relation."

> **Question.** Have any authors suggested such prefixes?

Comment: Er, assuming you mean the $1$ in a ring, not everyone agrees rings need those. And you should include "semigroup," though it really means no inverses too (but then, you've got to chuck inverses if you've chucked the identity.)

Comment: @AdamHughes, yes, I wasn't meaning to suggest that everyone includes a $1$ in a ring, but merely that pseudoring is widely used terminology for a ring that *emphatically* does not necessarily have an identity element, irrespective of one's background definitions.

Comment: Undoubtedly authors have suggested such things. Your real question is "what have they suggested?" right? If that's so, I think I agree that "semi" is often the way I hear these things go. Ultimately though it's probably just clearest to use more words and write exactly what is meant :)

Comment: I feel compelled to bring up the really cute terminology I've seen some people use: A "rng" is a ring without $1$, a "rig" is a ring without negation, a "rg" is a ring with neither.